# Why doesn't Blender Game Engine render worm gear mesh with all vertices and textures?

Tags: mesh, texturing, game-engine, vertices, text-object

Worm gear meshes in Blender Game Engine appear to render without many vertices, and without texture, when running the player. Rendering the same model in the viewport works fine. What is causing this? Is BGE supposed to render all vertices and textures?

Also, text with extruded depth, and texture, gets rendered as 2D text without extrusion or texture. Is this the same problem, or something else?

[image: Blender Game Engine render issues]

Update: Also a bug report here: https://developer.blender.org/T53181

Comment: Convert (a copy of) the text to mesh. Switch viewport rendering mode to GLSL. Make sure your scene is property lit

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Making a mesh from text gives it depth (extrusion). However this still doesn't get any texture. (Also it seems kind of hacky...) I've already set the Player shading to GLSL if that's what you mean. The scene has lots of light, I don't think that's affecting the visibility.

Comment: For textures to appear ingame you have to unwrap your meshes and use UV coordinates

Comment: Visibility: Ensure all face normals of the mesh are pointing outwards. Otherwise you will not see the mesh when seeing the backside.

Comment: By disabling backface culling I could get the other faces to show. For textures, I just tried selecting a textured object, edit mode, select all vertices, Mesh > Mesh UV Unwrap... > Unwrap. The texture already had Coordinates: UV. I added "UVMap" to the Map. The object still doesn't get any texture. Are any other actions necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The Game Engine by default hides back faces. By disabling backface culling (under the object's properties > material > game settings), I can make it render the faces.